# Update variables inside the jQuery $(document).ready() base scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, document-ready

I'm trying to find a way to minimize the number of Selector look-ups. My issue is that I have a variable defined with base $(document).ready() that needs to be updated inside functions nested inside $(document).ready()

Consider this example (EDIT: I updated it to be more explanatory)

```
<script>

//var $current_page = $home_page;  **<--I DONT want to do this, going global
                                        and of course it doesn't work since
                                        $home_page isn't defined yet.**

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $home_page = $("#home-page");
  var $portfolio_page = $("#portfolio-page");
  var $about_page = $("#about-page");
  var $current_page = $home_page;  // **<--This variable, in this scope level,
                                   //      is what I want updated**

  $("#home-btn").click(function () {
   $current_page.stop()
   $current_page.show()
   $current_page.animate({
    duration: 360, 
    easing: 'easeInCirc',
    complete: function() {
        $(this).css({ top: -700 });
    }

   ); 

   $current_page = $home_page;
  });

   $("#portfolio-btn").click(function () {
       $current_page.stop()
       $current_page.show()
       $current_page.animate({
         duration: 360, 
         easing: 'easeInCirc',
         complete: function() {
             $(this).css({ top: -700 });
         }

   ); 

   $current_page = $portfolio_page; //<--This needs to somehow update the
                                    //   variable in the $(document).ready
                                    //   scope, but not global**
  });
 });
 <script>
```

How can I update the variable $current_page **without** making it a global variable?

EDIT: 
This is done to animate out the current page div when you click on a menu item.  Yes, it's missing things, yes it may not make sense. It's just an example, not the actual application.

I understand this example is still trivial for performance, just ignore that fact. I just want to know how to do achieve this, not a lesson on whether it's the best practice or performance.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you show us and example of where you're running into performance issues? ID selector lookups are by far the fastest, and if you're running into performance issues, it might be a better idea to look at the specific bottleneck than try to micro-optimize on the selector level.

Comment: What's not happening with your current code?  Your example changes it in the method...but it was already set to this before the `click` handler was attached.  Are you wanting to re-run the selector to find new elements or something?

Comment: Your code is updateing $current_page. I don't get your question.
What do you want to do?

Comment: Regarding your edit: I don't see the problem; as I said below, the variable *is* in scope for the inner functions...

Answer (score 1):

The inner function creates a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closure), capturing the variables in the scope it is defined in. So you already have what you're asking for...

...whether that's a good idea or not is another matter.

For starters, you're not actually *modifying* the value in the code you listed - you're assigning `$current_page` the same value it was already initialized with.

But assuming you just omitted the code that you would normally use to pick a *different* value for `$current_page`, you need to ask yourself: is this really even *necessary*? You're performing a lookup based on an element ID and caching a reference to that element in a variable without knowing if or when you'll actually need it again. At best, this results in a potentially-unnecessary lookup; at worst, it can result in a memory leak. Why not just keep track of the ID itself, and look up the element when and where you actually need it? Don't worry about performance until you actually encounter a performance *problem*... or you may find that your premature optimization has caused more problems than it solves.

Same goes for `$home_page`, `$portfolio_page` and `$about_page` - you're making your page load (slightly) more slowly on the off-chance that you'll need a reference to those elements later on, when you could just as well look them up as-needed.

Comment: I agree. This is just a short example to show the scope issue, not the show where it would benefit from performance. (and I did omit another page change, thanks!)

I'm going to edit it show a more in-depth example.  The example does not update the $current_page variable (that is, if it was different then what was originally set in the document.ready scope.

I'm trying to find a way (regardless of people's comments about why) to update the variable in it's original scope, without resulting to going all the way down to global, just updating it in the document.ready scope.

Thank your your help.

Answer (score 0):

- *"How can I update the variable $current_page without making it a global variable?"*

  You can update it right now. The inner click-handler function can modify $current_page.
- *"I'm trying to find a way to minimize the number of Selector look-ups."*

  But it seems that in fact you're about to make more, if you're changing $current_page with another selector.

But it isn't really clear what you're really trying to do.